# Unable to ssh to Beaglebone Black via Putty on windows

Tags: ssh, putty, beagleboneblack

I am trying to connect SSH via putty to Beaglebone Black from my laptop running windows 7.

After powering up the BBB and installing required drivers of BBB on windows, I am able to browse 192.168.7.2 in Chrome browser. I also got IP (BBB) from Cloud9 IDE provided on BeagleBone Black website.

But after that, when I tried to ssh via Putty , it shows connection refused. i don't know how to solve this problem. kindly help

Steps I followed:

1. Connected USB cable to BBB and PC. Also connected Ethernet cable from router to BBB.
2. Installed drivers to PC running windows. (see screenshot below that BBB is connected).
3. Tried to connect to BBB by ssh via putty.

Below are the screenshots:
 [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try connecting through the Serial Port in Putty.  In device manager get the COM{X} Port number then set the speed at 115200.  Since it'll be a serial connection make sure to hit enter a couple times to test response.

This might help you start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

To get closer to the issue to get a FTDI serial debug cable, connect it to BBB, ssh to BBB using serial port. Then try to ssh from BBB to windows and vice-versa. This can help you a little bit to get some leads, can try `dmesg | grep ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

I have flashed new Debian image on BBB emmc and did ssh via putty. Then I got it. Later modified sshd_config to provide root login --> " PermitRootLogin yes".
And restarted the ssh service.
Then i was able to login as root.